# Fast shared data store available to both observers and controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern

I'd like to use an observer to set some data that may or may not be picked up by the controller for a subsequent page call (event data that needs to be logged in JS).

There is as far as I know no shared memory between observers and controllers and there's no access to the Session since the observer could be firing off an event that's not even request-based (a cron job for instance).

What's a simple way to log this data fast (i.e. not in DB) so that I can access it on a subsequent request? Do I need to use Reddis/Mongo etc?

Answer (score 0):

We use redis for some similar type applications. Works really well and development was fast.